# declaration of flow (flowtype) generic type

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm trying to declare and use a generic flow types. They work perfectly when the type is exported, and then imported into modules. However, when I try to move them into flow declarations, flow throws the following error:
**^^^^ Node. Application of polymorphic type needs . (Can use `*` for inferrable ones)**

This works:

*definitions/module.js*

```
export type Node<T:Object> = {
  node: T,
}

export type Connection<T:Object> = {
  edges: Array<Node<T>>,
}

export type BaseRelayNode = {
  __dataID__: GlobalID,
  [fieldName: string]: any,
}

export type BaseRelayConnection = Connection<BaseRelayNode>;
```

*flow/module.js*

```
declare type GlobalID = string;
```

However, I would like to get rid of definitions/module.js completely and m

This does not:

*flow/module.js*

```
declare type GlobalID = string;


declare type Node<T:Object> = {
  node: T,
}

declare type Connection<T:Object> = {
  edges: Array<Node<T>>,
}

declare type BaseRelayNode = {
  __dataID__: GlobalID,
  [fieldName: string]: any,
}

declare type BaseRelayConnection = Connection<BaseRelayNode>;
```

How can I fix the version with the type declarations to avoid having to export/import these types?

Comment: Can you post the full flow output?